# Multi-page, multi-row table with automatic line break and fixed centered cell sizes

Tags: tables, longtable, tabularx, multirow

I am pretty new to using latex, and I need to create a rather complex table. The title basically tells what I want to do. I have the following issues I want to solve:

- The table would continue for a bit longer, so I definitely need another page.
- As you can see some of the line don't make a line break e.g. *advanced augmentation*, i even wonder why this happens since the other times the line breaks just works
- The numbers in the multi rows are not vertically centered, e.g. the *5.2* should be a little below.

It's a bit frustrating, when i solve a issue on the one hand another part of the table breaks. Any good ideas?

Minimal running example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\begin{document}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
 \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{C{1.5cm}|C{2cm} C{2cm} Y}
    Chapter & Experiment & Hyperparameter & Range \\
    \hline
    5.1 & benchmark & None & Configuration as in Chapter 3.2 \\
    \hline
    \multirow{7}{*}{5.2} & learning rate                       & learning rate   & 0.00002, 0.00005, 0.0001, 0.00025 \\
    \cline{2-4}
                     & \multirow{6}{=}{basic augmentation} 
                     & aspect ratio      & $1\pm0.5$ times total height and width \\
                     & & cropping        & random $333\times333$ region \\
                     & & horizontal flip & probability of $50\%$    \\
                     & & rotation        & rotating up to $\pm 180\degree$ uniformly chosen\\
                     & & shearing        & random angle between $\pm 30\degree$ uniformly chosen    \\
                     & & scaling         & ratio between $0.5-2.0$ uniformly chosen \\
     \hline
     \multirow{16}{*}{5.2} & \multirow{2}{*}{brightness shift}                                                          & minimum brightness  &  X \\
                      & & maximum brightness &  X \\
                      \cline{2-4}
                      & \multirow{2}{*}{noise injection} & mean     & X \\
                      &                                  & variance & X \\
                      \cline{2-4}
                      & \multirow{2}{*}{patch shuffle}   & patch size  & X \\
                      &                                  & probability & X \\
                      \cline{2-4}
                      & \multirow{3}{*}{random erasing}   & maximum range & X \\
                      & & aspect ratio r\_2 & X \\
                      & & probability       & X \\
                      \cline{2-4}
                      & \multirow{7}{*}{advanced augmentation} & patch shuffle   & X  \\
                      & & scaling         & X  \\
                      & & horizontal flip & X  \\
                      & & vertical flip   & X  \\
                      & & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}brightness \\ shift\end{tabular}                            & X  \\
                      & \multicolumn{1}{l}{}      & aspect ratio    & X  \\
                      & \multicolumn{1}{l}{}      & shearing        & X  \\
      \hline
      5.3 & ablation study without augmentation & image cycle consistency loss weight & 0.1,0.2,0.5,1.0 \\
     
   \end{tabularx}
\caption{Searched hyperparameters \label{all_hyperparameter}}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

This is how it looks so far:

[image: Buggy-multi-page-multi-row-table]

Comment: `tabularx` can not break across pages. If you want mid-table pagebreaks while keeping `X` (or derived) column types in your table, switch to `xltabular`. To vertically center "advanced augmentation"  while allowing a linebreak between the words, use `\multirow{9}{=}{advanced augmentation}` instead.

Comment: okay with the `{=}` i could force the line break in _advanced augmentation_, but now it is left aligned, actually i want that centered as well.

Comment: Personally, I find your table quite hard to read, especially due to vertically centered contents in combination with contents spanning multiple lines. Also, why do you have chapter 5.2 twice in your table? Probably it would be better to remove the first column entirely (this would save quite a lot of space and thus helps avoiding linebreaks inside of the other columns). You could add the chapter number in a `\multicolumn` command right above the corresponding rows of your table.

Comment: @leandriis I agree that the table is hard to read. It is only part of the appendix and is only there to find a specific hyperparameter used for the experiments i did. I need to include the chapter numbers to make it easier to find the hyperparameter, so excluding them won't be an option. I think I will try your `\multicolumn` suggestion. To see if  `xltabular`  works i need to add some more entries.

Comment: What about something like this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLwPC.png

Comment: That looks a lot better then mine: [https://imgur.com/0Vbo8sb](https://imgur.com/0Vbo8sb)

Comment: The indention of _chapters_ helps a lot for readability. How do I indent it like this? I am also wondering if some horizontal lines would help for readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I propose this variant layout, which uses `geometry`, `xcolor` and `xltabular` (to break tabularx tables across pages):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{ xltabular, booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{gensymb}

\begin{document}

{\centering\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}\arrayrulecolor{SlateGrey}%
 \begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{!{\quad}m{3.6cm}>{\raggedleft}m{3.5cm}X}%
\caption{Searched hyperparameters \label{all_hyperparameter}} \\
      Experiment & Hyperparameter & Range \\
\addlinespace
    \endfirsthead
\caption[]{Searched hyperparameters (\emph{continued})} \\
     Experiment & Hyperparameter & Range \\
    \addlinespace
    \endhead
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{r}{\small\emph{To be continued}}
\endfoot
\bottomrule
 \endlastfoot
\rowcolor{Gainsboro!50!Lavender} \multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{\textsc{Chapter 5.1}} \\[0.5ex]
  benchmark & None & Configuration as in Chapter 3.2 \\[2ex]%
\rowcolor{Gainsboro!60!Lavender}\multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{ \textsc{Chapter 5.2}}\\[0.5ex]
 learning rate & learning rate & 0.00002, 0.00005, 0.0001, 0.00025 \\
     \cmidrule(l{1em}){1-3}
                    {basic augmentation} &
                     aspect ratio & $1\pm0.5$ times total height and width \\
                     & cropping & random $333\times333$ region \\
                     & horizontal flip & probability of $50\%$ \\
                     & rotation & rotating up to $\pm 180\degree$ uniformly chosen\\
                     & shearing & random angle between $\pm 30\degree$ uniformly chosen \\
                     & scaling & ratio between $0.5-2.0$ uniformly chosen \\
     \cmidrule(l{1em}){1-3}
    \multirow{2}{*}{brightness shift} & minimum brightness & X \\
 & maximum brightness & X \\
    \cmidrule(l{1em}){1-3}
 \multirow{2}{*}{noise injection} & mean & X \\
 & variance & X \\
    \cmidrule(l{1em}){1-3}
 \multirow{2}{*}{patch shuffle} & patch size & X \\
 & probability & X \\
    \cmidrule(l{1em}){1-3}
 \multirow{3}{*}{random erasing} & maximum range & X \\
 & aspect ratio r\_2 & X \\
 & probability & X \\
    \cmidrule(l{1em}){1-3}
 advanced \rlap{augmentation} & patch shuffle & X \\
 & scaling & X \\
 & horizontal flip & X \\
 & vertical flip & X \\
 &brightness shift & X \\%
 & aspect ratio & X \\
 & shearing & X \\[2ex]
 \rowcolor{Gainsboro!60!Lavender}\multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{\textsc{Chapter} 5.3} \\[0.5ex]
 ablation study without augmentation & image cycle consistency loss weight & 0.1,0.2,0.5,1.0
   \end{xltabular}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Bernard, i ran into some problems when importing it from my example to the main document. I use the [template](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis), and i get some undefined control sequence error. I think the issue is related to `arrayrulecolor` and `rowcolor` since they are written just plain in the text now. I import the xcolor package and the required options, so this cannot be the issue.

Comment: What are the undefined control sequences?

Comment: I managed to change the error from undefined control sequence to undefined color for SlateGrey, Gainsboro and Lavender by importing the colortbl package. I am assuming right now that my latex either uses some lower tex version or something, but I have no clue how to fix that.

Comment: This is how it [looks](https://imgur.com/a/Q9tiNW2), if you scroll down you can see the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two versions with more or less horizontal lines:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}


 \begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{@{\quad\quad}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{2.25cm} >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{2.5cm} X}
 \caption{Searched hyperparameters \label{all_hyperparameter}}\\
 \toprule
     Experiment            & Hyperparameter     & Range \\
    \midrule
    \endhead
    \multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{\itshape Chapter 5.1}\\ \addlinespace
     benchmark             & None               & Configuration as in Chapter 3.2 \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{\itshape Chapter 5.2}\\
    \addlinespace
     learning rate         & learning rate      & 0.00002, 0.00005, 0.0001, 0.00025 \\
    \addlinespace
     \multirow{2}{=}{basic augmentation}    & aspect ratio      & $1\pm0.5$ times total height and width \\
                           & cropping           & random $333\times333$ region \\
                           & horizontal flip    & probability of $50\%$    \\
                           & rotation           & rotating up to $\pm 180\degree$ uniformly chosen\\
                           & shearing           & random angle between $\pm 30\degree$ uniformly chosen    \\
                           & scaling            & ratio between $0.5-2.0$ uniformly chosen \\
   \addlinespace
     brightness shift      & maximum brightness & X \\
    \addlinespace
     noise injection       & mean               & X \\
                           & variance           & X \\
    \addlinespace
     patch shuffle         & patch size         & X \\
                           & probability        & X \\
    \addlinespace
     \multirow{2}{=}{random erasing}        & maximum range      & X \\
                           & aspect ratio r\_2  & X \\
                           & probability        & X \\
    \addlinespace
     \multirow{2}{=}{advanced augmentation} & patch shuffle      & X  \\
                           & scaling            & X  \\
                           & horizontal flip    & X  \\
                           & vertical flip      & X  \\
                           & brightness  shift  & X  \\
                           & aspect ratio       & X  \\
                           & shearing           & X  \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{\itshape Chapter 5.3}\\ \addlinespace
   ablation study without augmentation & image cycle consistency loss weight & 0.1,0.2,0.5,1.0 \\
     
   \end{xltabular}


 \begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{@{\quad\quad}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{2.25cm} >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{2.5cm} X}
 \caption{Searched hyperparameters \label{all_hyperparameter}}\\
 \toprule
     Experiment            & Hyperparameter     & Range \\
    \midrule
    \endhead
    \multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{\itshape Chapter 5.1}\\ \addlinespace
     benchmark             & None               & Configuration as in Chapter 3.2 \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{\itshape Chapter 5.2}\\
    \addlinespace
     learning rate         & learning rate      & 0.00002, 0.00005, 0.0001, 0.00025 \\
    \midrule
     \multirow{2}{=}{basic augmentation}    & aspect ratio      & $1\pm0.5$ times total height and width \\
                           & cropping           & random $333\times333$ region \\
                           & horizontal flip    & probability of $50\%$    \\
                           & rotation           & rotating up to $\pm 180\degree$ uniformly chosen\\
                           & shearing           & random angle between $\pm 30\degree$ uniformly chosen    \\
                           & scaling            & ratio between $0.5-2.0$ uniformly chosen \\
   \midrule
     brightness shift      & maximum brightness & X \\
    \midrule
     noise injection       & mean               & X \\
                           & variance           & X \\
    \midrule
     patch shuffle         & patch size         & X \\
                           & probability        & X \\
    \midrule
     \multirow{2}{=}{random erasing}        & maximum range      & X \\
                           & aspect ratio r\_2  & X \\
                           & probability        & X \\
    \midrule
     \multirow{2}{=}{advanced augmentation} & patch shuffle      & X  \\
                           & scaling            & X  \\
                           & horizontal flip    & X  \\
                           & vertical flip      & X  \\
                           & brightness  shift  & X  \\
                           & aspect ratio       & X  \\
                           & shearing           & X  \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{\itshape Chapter 5.3}\\ \addlinespace
   ablation study without augmentation & image cycle consistency loss weight & 0.1,0.2,0.5,1.0 \\
     
   \end{xltabular}
\end{document}
```